# monodroid: how to create receiver/meta-data clause in manisfest.xml

Tags: xamarin.android

I note the the mono android port of the SDK API Demos does not include the DeviceAdministration pieces.

Is this because it (DeviceAdmin) doesnt work? I have tried to make a small sample app and have not succeeded.

EDIT: Well I got a fair way in, now my problem is that I cannot generate the receiver/meta-data clause

I am on my way to writing my own aapt.exe to intercept the xml file on its way through  this seems like a lot of heavy lifting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [[BroadcastReceiverAttribute](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.BroadcastReceiverAttribute)] custom attribute to generate the `<receiver/>` element, and you can use the [[MetaDataAttribute](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.App.MetaDataAttribute)] custom attribute to generate the `<meta-data/>` element:

```csharp
[BroadcastReceiver]
[MetaData ("foo", Value="bar")]
public class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {
}
```

Would generate the XML fragment within AndroidManifest:

```xml
<receiver android:name="generated-by-mandroid">
    <meta-data android:name="foo" android:value="bar" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: awesome - how did i miss that attribute! I spent a long time with reflector looking for it and failed

Comment: @jonp do you know if the BroadcastReceiver is delibertaley missing a Description property? Without that I cannot add the Description attribute to the manifest